# Deep Neural Network using Keras/Tensorflow solves Spiral Dataset Classification. But Accuracy is stuck around 50%

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have created a deep neural network that solves the spiral dataset classification problem. However, when measuring the performance, the accuracy goes up and down but always stays at around 50% - which is of course very bad.

The image below shows loss and accuracy of 100 epochs of training.

[image: Loss and accuracy of 100 epochs of training.]

How can I fix this? I have done research and I don't see where the error is in my code. Is the error in the architecture of my network?

My code:

```
# Make sure we have the required libraries loaded
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(ggplot2)

# Load the data
spiralData = read.table("spiral.data", header=TRUE)  

# Visualize the data
qplot(x, y, data = spiralData, colour = label)

# Store the data in features and labels.
x<-c(spiralData$x)
y<-c(spiralData$y)
features <- matrix(c(x,y),nrow=length(x))
labels <- matrix(spiralData$label)

# Create model.
model <- keras_model_sequential()

# Add layers and compile the model.
# Our model consists of 4 hidden layers, each with 6 neurons.
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 6, activation = 'tanh', input_shape = c(2)) %>%  
  layer_dense(units = 6, activation = 'tanh') %>%   
  layer_dense(units = 6, activation = 'tanh') %>%  
  layer_dense(units = 6, activation = 'tanh') %>%   
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid') %>% 
  compile(
    optimizer = 'rmsprop',
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  )

# Train the model, iterating on the data in batches of 32 samples.
# Also, visualize the training process.
model %>% fit(features, labels, epochs=100, batch_size=32)

# Evalute the model
score = model %>% evaluate(features, labels, batch_size=32)
print(score)
```

My "spiral.data" dataset:

```
x y label
1 0 1
-1 0 0
0.971354 0.209317 1
-0.971354 -0.209317 0
0.906112 0.406602 1
-0.906112 -0.406602 0
0.807485 0.584507 1
-0.807485 -0.584507 0
0.679909 0.736572 1
-0.679909 -0.736572 0
0.528858 0.857455 1
-0.528858 -0.857455 0
0.360603 0.943128 1
-0.360603 -0.943128 0
0.181957 0.991002 1
-0.181957 -0.991002 0
-3.07692e-06 1 1
3.07692e-06 -1 0
-0.178211 0.970568 1
0.178211 -0.970568 0
-0.345891 0.90463 1
0.345891 -0.90463 0
-0.496812 0.805483 1
0.496812 -0.805483 0
-0.625522 0.67764 1
0.625522 -0.67764 0
-0.727538 0.52663 1
0.727538 -0.52663 0
-0.799514 0.35876 1
0.799514 -0.35876 0
-0.839328 0.180858 1
0.839328 -0.180858 0
-0.846154 -6.66667e-06 1
0.846154 6.66667e-06 0
-0.820463 -0.176808 1
0.820463 0.176808 0
-0.763975 -0.342827 1
0.763975 0.342827 0
-0.679563 -0.491918 1
0.679563 0.491918 0
-0.57112 -0.618723 1
0.57112 0.618723 0
-0.443382 -0.71888 1
0.443382 0.71888 0
-0.301723 -0.78915 1
0.301723 0.78915 0
-0.151937 -0.82754 1
0.151937 0.82754 0
9.23077e-06 -0.833333 1
-9.23077e-06 0.833333 0
0.148202 -0.807103 1
-0.148202 0.807103 0
0.287022 -0.750648 1
-0.287022 0.750648 0
0.411343 -0.666902 1
-0.411343 0.666902 0
0.516738 -0.559785 1
-0.516738 0.559785 0
0.599623 -0.43403 1
-0.599623 0.43403 0
0.65738 -0.294975 1
-0.65738 0.294975 0
0.688438 -0.14834 1
-0.688438 0.14834 0
0.692308 1.16667e-05 1
-0.692308 -1.16667e-05 0
0.669572 0.144297 1
-0.669572 -0.144297 0
0.621838 0.27905 1
-0.621838 -0.27905 0
0.551642 0.399325 1
-0.551642 -0.399325 0
0.462331 0.500875 1
-0.462331 -0.500875 0
0.357906 0.580303 1
-0.357906 -0.580303 0
0.242846 0.635172 1
-0.242846 -0.635172 0
0.12192 0.664075 1
-0.12192 -0.664075 0
-1.07692e-05 0.666667 1
1.07692e-05 -0.666667 0
-0.118191 0.643638 1
0.118191 -0.643638 0
-0.228149 0.596667 1
0.228149 -0.596667 0
-0.325872 0.528323 1
0.325872 -0.528323 0
-0.407954 0.441933 1
0.407954 -0.441933 0
-0.471706 0.341433 1
0.471706 -0.341433 0
-0.515245 0.231193 1
0.515245 -0.231193 0
-0.537548 0.115822 1
0.537548 -0.115822 0
-0.538462 -1.33333e-05 1
0.538462 1.33333e-05 0
-0.518682 -0.111783 1
0.518682 0.111783 0
-0.479702 -0.215272 1
0.479702 0.215272 0
-0.423723 -0.306732 1
0.423723 0.306732 0
-0.353545 -0.383025 1
0.353545 0.383025 0
-0.272434 -0.441725 1
0.272434 0.441725 0
-0.183971 -0.481192 1
0.183971 0.481192 0
-0.0919062 -0.500612 1
0.0919062 0.500612 0
1.23077e-05 -0.5 1
-1.23077e-05 0.5 0
0.0881769 -0.480173 1
-0.0881769 0.480173 0
0.169275 -0.442687 1
-0.169275 0.442687 0
0.2404 -0.389745 1
-0.2404 0.389745 0
0.299169 -0.324082 1
-0.299169 0.324082 0
0.343788 -0.248838 1
-0.343788 0.248838 0
0.373109 -0.167412 1
-0.373109 0.167412 0
0.386658 -0.0833083 1
-0.386658 0.0833083 0
0.384615 1.16667e-05 1
-0.384615 -1.16667e-05 0
0.367792 0.0792667 1
-0.367792 -0.0792667 0
0.337568 0.15149 1
-0.337568 -0.15149 0
0.295805 0.214137 1
-0.295805 -0.214137 0
0.24476 0.265173 1
-0.24476 -0.265173 0
0.186962 0.303147 1
-0.186962 -0.303147 0
0.125098 0.327212 1
-0.125098 -0.327212 0
0.0618938 0.337147 1
-0.0618938 -0.337147 0
-1.07692e-05 0.333333 1
1.07692e-05 -0.333333 0
-0.0581615 0.31671 1
0.0581615 -0.31671 0
-0.110398 0.288708 1
0.110398 -0.288708 0
-0.154926 0.251167 1
0.154926 -0.251167 0
-0.190382 0.206232 1
0.190382 -0.206232 0
-0.215868 0.156247 1
0.215868 -0.156247 0
-0.230974 0.103635 1
0.230974 -0.103635 0
-0.235768 0.050795 1
0.235768 -0.050795 0
-0.230769 -1e-05 1
0.230769 1e-05 0
-0.216903 -0.0467483 1
0.216903 0.0467483 0
-0.195432 -0.0877067 1
0.195432 0.0877067 0
-0.167889 -0.121538 1
0.167889 0.121538 0
-0.135977 -0.14732 1
0.135977 0.14732 0
-0.101492 -0.164567 1
0.101492 0.164567 0
-0.0662277 -0.17323 1
0.0662277 0.17323 0
-0.0318831 -0.173682 1
0.0318831 0.173682 0
6.15385e-06 -0.166667 1
-6.15385e-06 0.166667 0
0.0281431 -0.153247 1
-0.0281431 0.153247 0
0.05152 -0.13473 1
-0.05152 0.13473 0
0.0694508 -0.112592 1
-0.0694508 0.112592 0
0.0815923 -0.088385 1
-0.0815923 0.088385 0
0.0879462 -0.063655 1
-0.0879462 0.063655 0
0.0888369 -0.0398583 1
-0.0888369 0.0398583 0
0.0848769 -0.018285 1
-0.0848769 0.018285 0
0.0769231 3.33333e-06 1
-0.0769231 -3.33333e-06 0
```

Visualized, the dataset looks like this:

[image]

Comment: The loss looks like it is still dropping (noisily). Have you tried running for many more epochs? When the data set size is small it is quite common to need to do this, and you also have a deep network with activation function that will tend to train slowly.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thank you for your comment. I have tried to run it for 1000 epochs, but still no good results: https://i.imgur.com/JvOR7mM.png. What else can I try?

Comment: Maybe change the hidden layer activation to `relu` and/or increase number of hidden units. I might have a look at the data set later on, to see what the simplest explainable change might be to improve performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your network is actually working, it just takes a lot of epochs to learn the spiral. In fact you can see from your learning curves that learning is still occurring, just not much per epoch.

Try 60,000 epochs . . . when I try your model (in Python, but still same data and model) using 60,000 epochs I get loss under 0.0001 and accuracy of 100% reliably.

There are a few factors involved in why you need this amount of iteration:

- The data set size is small, which means you get less updates to weights per epoch. You need to compensate by increasing the number of iterations.
- You have a "starved" network topology that can just about learn the spiral, but needs to be quite precisely optimised before it starts performing well. You could increase the number of neurons per hidden layer slightly. Or maybe adding another hidden layer:

  - If I add one more hidden layer, size 6, `tanh` activation, the network learns 100% accuracy in under 20,000 epochs.
  - If instead, I increase the original four hidden layers to size 16, the network learns 100% accuracy in under 10,000 epochs.
- `tanh` is not optimal for a deep network, because the gradient diminishes in the deeper parts of the model. RMSProp will compensate for that, but still changing to `relu` will improve convergence speed.

  - If I use the four-hidden-layer model, with layer size 16 and `relu` activation, the network converges to 100% accuracy on the training data set in around 2000 epochs.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(4375689)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

train_data = pd.read_csv('spirals.csv').values
train_X = train_data[:,0:2]
train_y = train_data[:,2]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,)))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=RMSprop(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=32, epochs=2000, verbose=0)

score = model.evaluate(train_X, train_y, verbose=0)

print(score)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this insightful comment! I also got it working in R now.